# What caused the infertility?

Tags: plot-explanation, children-of-men

I had watched Children of men recently, I'm confused in one aspect

What caused the infertility?

Answer (score 11):

The source/cause of the infertility is never explained in the movie and very likely unknown. This, in many ways, is what the *Human Project* is trying to ascertain in order to find a cure.

While the women are the ones said to be infertile in the film, it's the men who are infertile (zero sperm count) in the original [P.D. James novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Children_of_Men).

Comment: And this uncertainty of the reasons emphasizes this whole hopeless and desperate world situation even more, I think.

Answer (score -1):

Pretty sure I remember them saying something about a pandemic rendering all women infertile.

Comment: Welcome to the site! While I believe you are correct, if you could add more context or be more specific, your answer would be more readily accepted. Add some links or details ... flesh it out a little. If you don't, your answer may be deleted as irrelevant.